# re.search to get decimal number

Tags: python, text-processing

I am trying to get a number from a text file. I need the full decimal number. 
The line looks like:

```
corner_lat:     49.0425000  decimal degrees
```

I'm trying this

```
    if "corner_lat" in line:
        nlines = re.search(r'(\d+)\D+', line).group(1)
        nlines = float(nlines)  # type:
        print(nlines)
```

But I get only one decimal (49.0). How should I change my re.search to get the full number?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern, `(\d+)` matches only digits and catches just the `49`. 
In the next line you convert that `49` to a float resulting in `49.0`.

Adjust the pattern to either match *digits and dots* or to match *digits*, *one dot*, followed by *digits*:

```
# match arbitrary number and order of digits and dots.
# Note that this also would match "49.123.4.5":
nlines = re.search(r'([\d.]+)\D+', line).group(1)

# or match N digits, ONE dot, N digits:
nlines = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)\D+', line).group(1)
```

You can also omit the `\D` part because regexes are by default *greedy*: they try to pick as many digits as possible while still fullfilling the overall pattern. In other words, it tries to find the longest possible sequence of *digits*, *dot*, *digits* and thus automatically stops at a non-digit (`\D`):

```
nlines = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)', line).group(1)
```

Note: We need to escape the dot `\.` when outside a *character class* because a dot matches *any* character. This is not needed when inside a character class, i.e. `[.]` doesn't match *any* character, but just a literal dot.